# Flutter showing old errors

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

I was writing a flutter application but when I want to test it on the Android Emulator (Ctrl+F5) I get an unfixable error. This is part of it:

```
I/flutter (13782): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (13782): The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
I/flutter (13782): Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.
I/flutter (13782): Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container. In this case, a vertical
I/flutter (13782): viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand. This situation
I/flutter (13782): typically happens when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget.
I/flutter (13782): If this widget is always nested in a scrollable widget there is no need to use a viewport because
I/flutter (13782): there will always be enough vertical space for the children. In this case, consider using a Column
I/flutter (13782): instead. Otherwise, consider using the "shrinkWrap" property (or a ShrinkWrappingViewport) to size
I/flutter (13782): the height of the viewport to the sum of the heights of its children.
I/flutter (13782):
I/flutter (13782): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter (13782):   ListView  (file:///D:/flutterProjects/test_project/test_project/lib/screens/all_obj_screen.dart:19:18)
```

As you can see in the last line it says the cause of the error is a `ListView` in `D:/flutterProjects/test_project/test_project/lib/screens/all_obj_screen.dart`. The problem is that I have no `ListView` in that file (at the moment, but I had it previously) and that path does not even exist anymore!

If it can help, this is the `all_obj_screen.dart` file:

```
class AllObjScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AllObjScreenState createState() => _AllObjScreenState();
}

class _AllObjScreenState extends State<AllObjScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final objects = Provider.of<Objs>(context);

    return Center(
      child: Text(
        '${objects.items.length}',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 25,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So I am thinking that the problem is not my code but something about Visual Studio Code. How to fix this problem?

EDIT:
I have tried to run the app on both Visual Studio Code and on Android Studio but the problem is the same.
I have also tried to reinstall the IDE and flutter but no luck at all.

Comment: I get the same issues with my Flutter app, if you hot restart the app it goes away until you fully restart the app where you have to hot restart it again. However, you could run `flutter clean` and it should go away.

Comment: Hmm could it be some sort of cached build? Clean caches, reinstall, close and reopen .. etc?

Comment: @Benjamin I tried to hot reload and even to use flutter clean but the problem is still there

Comment: @PFuster I have already tried to do all those things...

Comment: Does this happen in Android Studio or another IDE?

Comment: @Benjamin I've just tried with Android Studio and it happens in there too... I'm so confused

Comment: I'd file an issue in the Flutter GitHub [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues).

Comment: did you try flutter clean ?

Comment: @Salma. Look above in the comments...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same problem since version 1.12. 
Rebooting device clears logs but I hope Flutter will correct this in future versions.
This just happend using android devices. In iOS works correctly.

Answer (score 3):

**The short answer:** Wipe data or Delete that device (emulator) and create another new one.

[image]

**The long story:**

I had the same exact issue! The code was perfect and suddenly without any change I get a big list of errors based on events that shouldn't be fired!

I tried `flutter clean` and it didn't solve the issue and tried everything even I deleted all the code that handles the wrongly fired event and I had no luck with that errors which keep coming again and again while no code to generate them!!.

Until I thought about trying another emulator and the magic happened! No errors!

Comment: Wipe data not enough?

Comment: @kkonrad try and tell us, please. If it worked for you I would edit my answer

Comment: wiping data worked

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
flutter logs -c
```

(to clear logs, run in the project directory)

After cleaning process, then press CTRL + C and answer Y for the question follow. Hope it will help. Thx

Answer (score 1):

you can see it: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/46815.
This issue is fixed in flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix8.